# About the security of the CodeIgniter View files

Tags: php, codeigniter

In beginning of the libraries and models etc. of the CodeIgniter, we have this line which prohibits any direct and thus illegitimate access:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

should (or must) the view files have this line at their beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to avoid it because the view files does not contain any security code usually, if you any, then that's another story...